# load javascript files run-time

Tags: javascript

I have a script which load a javascript file run-time or async

```
var s = document.createElement('script');
s.type = 'text/javascript';
s.src = 'file.js';
s.onreadystatechange = function(){
    console.log(this.readyState)
};
s.onload = function(){
    console.log('onload')
};
body.appendChild(s);
```

The problem is that when `s.onload` is triggered and `onload` is printed in the console the script isn't loaded completely and when calling a function from the file `undefined` is returned

If a `setTimeout` is setup after the script is onload it works, but that isn't good practice

Have made some research on the topic and found the `onreadystatechange` event.. But the event is never triggered in my code?!

How to add an event which is triggered when the script is completely loaded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order is important. Append the element first and add the src last:

```
var s = document.createElement('script');
s.type = 'text/javascript';

body.appendChild(s);

s.onreadystatechange = function(){
    console.log(this.readyState)
};
s.onload = function(){
    console.log('onload')
};

s.src = 'file.js';
```